# Convert whole grease pencil animation to mesh?

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil

I know it's possible to convert a grease pencil drawing into a mesh but how about a full animation ? I've tried with "convert Grease Pencil" but it creates a Bézier curve that freezes the animation on the frame I am on.[image]

Comment: I made a tool that can port your animations over if they were loops and convert them to meshes. I'm going to make it so you can convert lines in the future but I can't promise when though. [Shady Pencil](https://github.com/ahkCodeder/Shady-Pencil/tree/Shady_Pencil-v1-alpha)